# WFS query do not preview all records for GeoJSON file

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I am running a GetFeature request against a WFS server which does not support to download all data at once. I have 910 features and only 200 are visualized. Here is what I tried:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pqi_data/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=pqi_data%3Acentros_saude_4326&maxFeatures=200&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript
```

My WFS version is 1.0.0 (old) and my GeoServer is 2.16.

I found startindex option but it never works. I think that is due to the versions.

If I changed the parameter maxFeatures to 910, an error appears and the log file has this content:

```
2020-06-18 11:57:32,757 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-06-18 11:57:32,767 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        typeName[0] = {pqi_data.com}centros_saude_4326
    maxFeatures = 910
    outputFormat = text/javascript
    resultType = results
2020-06-18 11:57:32,770 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2020-06-18 11:57:32,839 INFO [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
2020-06-18 11:57:32,839 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.write(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:198)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1031)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.testValidity(JSONUtils.java:597)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.numberToString(JSONUtils.java:443)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.valueToString(JSONUtils.java:668)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONBuilder.value(JSONBuilder.java:326)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.value(GeoJSONBuilder.java:381)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.value(GeoJSONBuilder.java:34)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONBuilder.value(JSONBuilder.java:302)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.roundedValue(GeoJSONBuilder.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeCoordinate(GeoJSONBuilder.java:188)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeCoordinate(GeoJSONBuilder.java:137)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeGeom(GeoJSONBuilder.java:67)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.encodeSimpleFeatures(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:428)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.writeFeatures(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.write(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:133)
    ... 95 more
```

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in data, see the error `Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers`.

Comment: But how can I see if the issue is in the data? In the attributes? If I preview in GEOSERVER as GML, it works fine for instance.

Comment: I guess that GML supports non-finite numbers and therefore you do not get an error. Or maybe GML preview is using maxFeatures and the error appears later in the data. Compare with GML output and try to find the plase where "non-finite numbers" appear. Perhaps you can locate the problematic feature by using GeoJSON format and increasing the maxFeatures value from 200 until you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You told GeoServer that you only wanted 200 features returned when you set `maxFeatures=200` in the URL - if you want all the features then don't add a `maxFeatures` parameter.

Your other problems are that your features contain a NaN or Infinity value that can't be written out using JSON, you will need to fix your data if you want to continue to use JSON as an output format.

Comment: I changed also that parameter to 910. But an error appears. I try with all values and 200 is the maximum accepted.

Comment: If I change the maxFeatures to 910, the following error appears: This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: any value should work but leaving it out completely is easiest

Comment: I try with values > 200 in maxFeatures and I get always the same error. Can you help me?

Comment: check the log file to see what the full error is and use the [edit] link to update your question to what it actually is

Comment: Probably first 200 features don't contain error in data. Try to inspect logs to check which feature/s causes problems. If you try to get more than 200 features, error occur. If you use WFS 1.0.0. then you can iterate features with maxFeatures and startIndex parameters. If you use WFS 2.0.0. then you can use parameters count and startIndex.

Comment: I see the data and it is the same in all fields. There are some cells as NULL but there are also in the first 200 features.

Comment: then you'll need to either turn logging up and hope the actual value gets logged at some point or attach a debugger to GeoServer (at GeoJSONBuilder.java:381) and see what triggers the exception

Comment: I get it!!! I do not know program well in javascript. I open the shapefile in GIS software and I see that there is something wrong with the extention of the file. So I change my shapefile, uploaded again to PostGIS and GEOSERVER and know it works fine. So, it was an error in the extension of the original file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

At least with this server maxFeatures and startIndex work as supposed. Or not really, because support for startIndex came in WFS version 2.0, but GeoServers do support it also with older versions.

This returns Illinois

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typename=states&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=1&startIndex=0

This returns Georgia

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typename=states&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=1&startIndex=10

Georgia as GeoJSON

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typename=states&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json&maxfeatures=1&startIndex=10

Comment: I try with the last URL and not working as well. I put maxfeatures=910

Comment: GeoJSON is not the native format for WFS and GeoServer may not support everything with that outputformat perfectly. I guess that the output as GML is correct http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typename=states&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=910&startIndex=10.